# Converting Java object to JSON with specific syntax

Tags: java, json, serialization

I want to convert Java object to JSON string. Lets say the object looks like this:

```
public class User{
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
}
```

And the json should look like this:

```
{
    "inputFields":[
        {
            "name":"id",
            "value":"123"
        },
        {
            "name":"firstName",
            "value":"George"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried to use Jackson, but it looks like it doesn't provide such kind of serialization.

Comment: You Need Custom Serializer to `Serialize` the array of Class `User` Object.

Comment: This is what you need to do: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: Why do you need such an awkward JSON structure? Wouldn't it be better to have `"id":"123","name":"George"`?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this thread - [How to serialize Object to JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607444/how-to-serialize-object-to-json)

Comment: @BadCash, there always is a reason. For this case I am trying to integrate with external WebService, and it requires such structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson can use custom serializer where you can have control in generating the output.
The following are the step to do this:

Annotate your POJO to use a custom serializer

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
static class User{
    public Long id;
    public String firstName;

    public User(Long id, String firstName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

Declare the serialzer

```
static class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer{

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("inputFields");

        Field[] fields = value.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                jgen.writeStartObject();
                jgen.writeObjectField("name", field.getName());
                jgen.writeObjectField("value", field.get(value));
                jgen.writeEndObject();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        jgen.writeEndArray();
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

A simple test

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    User user = new User(1L, "Mike");
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.writeValueAsString(user);
    System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(user));
}
```

And the output will be

```
{"inputFields":[{"name":"id","value":1},{"name":"firstName","value":"Mike"}]}
```

Comment: what version of jackson are you using ?

Comment: in the example i used jackson 2.6.1

Comment: add `field.setAccessible(true);` to the loop and I will accept this answer as the most "on point" and elegant.

Comment: true, to prevent accessibility using reflection one should set that flag. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an `InputFields` class and move the `User` object data to it before converting to json.

Edit: The InputFields class would obviously have the same structure as the desired json result.

Comment: And make the field a Collection inside the InputFields class. Or create a custom converter.

Comment: @stepanian actually, the inputFields is not a big problem, the problem is structure of name-value pairs

Comment: I understand that. The InputFields class will have that structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just a example of stepanian's answer, but i prefer dumitru's way to implement a CustomSerializer.

1. create a InputField class

   ```
   public class InputField {

       private String name;
       private String value;

       public String getValue() {
           return value;
       }

       public void setValue(String value) {
           this.value = value;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

   }
   ```
2. parse User

   ```
   public static List<InputField> parseInputFields(Object model) {
       List<InputField> inputFields = new ArrayList<InputField>();

       Field[] field = model.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
       try {
           for (int j = 0; j < field.length; j++) {

               InputField inputField = new InputField();

               inputField.setName(field[j].getName());
               inputField.setValue(String.valueOf(field[j].get(model));

               inputFields.add(inputField);
           }
       } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SecurityException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return inputFields;
   }
   ```
3. test

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
       User user = new User(1L, "Mike");

       Map<String, Object> tmpMap=new HashedMap();
       tmpMap.put("inputFields", parseInputFields(user));

       ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
       System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(tmpMap));
   }
   ```