# Save generic object in database

Tags: android, database, android-database

My model is like:

```
public class MyModel{
    private String mId;
    private String mName;
    T mAnObject;
}
```

How can I store T object in `database`.

Comment: In which form you want, as an object or as a json/string?

Comment: @AndreiT If it can be object then will be more feasible for me

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can't store an object in a database. You need to serialize and deserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save specific properties, just do that, otherwise you could serialize it to `JSON`, as an option (as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607444/how-to-serialize-object-to-json)).

Answer (score 0):

Example:
Object myObj has three properties: String title, String subtitle, String text

1 - You can save them as separate database rows and then when you read from the database you recombine them to create your Object.

2 - You can also use Json to save the properties, this way you only need to store a single String in the database and when you read from the database convert the Json String to your Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it with JsonNode class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).