# java - parsing custom file by tag

Tags: java, parsing

I have a file formated .TXT like this :

```
[Quest]
Name: The Adventure
Creator: Darius
Reward: 0g

[@New Monster]
MonsterID: 100
MonsterHP: 23987
MonsterLv: 11
MonsterDmg: 133
MonsterType: Magic

[@New Monster]
MonsterID: 101
MonsterHP: 21236
MonsterLv: 8
MonsterDmg: 95
MonsterType: Physical

[@New Item]
ItemID: 222
ItemDamage: 88
ItemType: Robe
```

How can i parse this file so i can get the monsterid,monsterhp etc and itemId,itemdamage etc. There is two [@New Monsters]

Comment: Is there a reason beyond learning why you are re-inventing file formats? If not, using a standard format makes it easier to edit, read, and use programmatically.

Comment: Do you save the text in the file by yourself? If yes, you can write a class as data model for Monster, Quest, Item and serialize/deserialize it as JSON in your txt file. For example how easy it is to get a JSON string from an object look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607559/5056173

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I wanted to know how to parse this code.

Comment: @SeanStayn i made this file so people can create custom quest in my game, people create the file, so my program parse it as a quest in my game.

Comment: @user7294900 i only can parse the first tag "[Quest]" about the other tag, i cant solve it now.

Comment: @DariusEllertKlaus "i only can parse the first tag "[Quest]" about the other tag, i cant solve it now." That's fine, show us what you have done, it shows you have put some effort in and can provide insight into what you mis-understand.

Comment: "i made this file so people can create custom quest in my game" - so why not use JSON or XML, which will be more familiar to other people, and allow you to use existing parsers?

Comment: @JonSkeet i dont want to use json or xml, i still learning this thing, as i said about, i wanted to know how to parse this code.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach my code is very bad, its even cant be called parse :(

Comment: You can use `java.util.Scanner` to parse file manually. When you read line  `[@New Monster]` create object of class `Monster` and populate it with following properties