# Handling null value while dynamically converting resultset to JSON

Tags: java

I am converting the resultset to JSON using the following approach and trying to figure out how to handle `null` value based on the scenario described below:

When I run the following SQL query (which is used in the code below) in Oracle SQL developer :

`SELECT SQLQUERY FROM EMP WHERE id = 6`, I get the following result:

```
  Employee State of Residence     Employee Count
1  (null)                         1400
2  AL                             1200
3  MS                             6700
4  WT                             4
```

As seen above,for the above data returned by the above SQL query, the Java code below is converting it into the following JSON :

```
[{
        "Employee Count": "           1400"
    },
    {
        "Employee Count": "           1200",
        "Employee State of Residence": "AL"
    },
    {
        "Employee Count": "              6700",
        "Employee State of Residence": "MS"
    },
    {
        "Employee Count": "              4",
        "Employee State of Residence": "WT"
    }
]
```

So basically, it didn't display the `Employee State of Residence` column name in the JSON response for Employee Count `1400` above because it's `null`.How can I make sure that in case of `null` value, it 
displays the column name with maybe an empty string? OR should I ask the database person to return something if it's `NULL`?

```
@Override
    public String getData(Integer id) throws DaoException {

        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmtNew = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;    
        ResultSet rsNew = null;

        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

        try {
            ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
            conn = ds.getConnection();          
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT SQLQUERY FROM EMP WHERE id = ?");
            pstmt.setInt(1, id);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  
            rs.next();

            String sqlQuery = rs.getString("SQLQUERY");
            pstmtNew = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            rsNew = pstmtNew.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsNew.getMetaData();
            int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            logger.info("Total Column Count "+rsmd.getColumnCount());
            logger.info("The query fetched %d columns\n",cols);
            logger.info("These columns are: ");

             for (int i=1;i<=cols;i++) {
                 String colName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                 String colType = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i);                 
                 logger.info(colName+" of type "+colType);
              }

             while(rsNew.next()) {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                for (int i=1;i<=cols;i++) {

                     String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);


                     if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.ARRAY) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getArray(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BIGINT) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getInt(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getBoolean(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BLOB) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getBlob(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DOUBLE) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getDouble(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.FLOAT) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getFloat(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.INTEGER) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getInt(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getNString(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getString(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TINYINT) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getInt(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.SMALLINT) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getInt(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DATE) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getDate(column_name));
                        } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getTimestamp(column_name));
                        } else {
                         obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getObject(column_name));
                        }

             }
                 json.put(obj);
            }



        }
        catch(Throwable th) {
            throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
        }
        finally {
            if (rs != null) { try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
            if (rsNew != null) { try { rsNew.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
            if (pstmt != null) { try { pstmt.close(); } catch(SQLException sqe) { sqe.printStackTrace(); }}
            if (pstmtNew != null) { try { pstmtNew.close(); } catch(SQLException sqe) { sqe.printStackTrace(); }}
            if (conn != null) { try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) { sqle.printStackTrace(); }}
        }
        return json.toString(); 

    }
```

The following log statements are printing the following:

```
logger.info("Total Column Count "+rsmd.getColumnCount());
            logger.info("The query fetched %d columns\n",cols);
            logger.info("These columns are: ");

            Total Column Count 2
            The query fetched %d columns
            These columns are:
            Employee State of Residence of type VARCHAR2
            Employee Count of type VARCHAR2
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply check for null in the code you've written above and output an empty string?

Comment: Could you tell me where and how? I am little confused. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607559/102937) be easier?  It has a [Serialize Null Fields](http://tutorialtous.com/gson/serializingNullFields.php) option.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I used these lines of code inside `else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)` to explicitly check the null value `if(rsNew.getString(column_name) == null) { 
                  obj.put(column_name, "");          
          } else
         {obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getString(column_name));}` Is this what you were referring to in your first comment? It works after adding this explicit check. I might have to do this explicit check for others as well.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of a limitation in JSONObject. You need to place a JSONObject.NULL in order to see an entry in your JSON object.  I would try modifying your code to the following:

```
} else {
    Object object = rsNew.getObject(column_name);
    if (object != null) {
      obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getObject(column_name));
    } else {
      obj.put(column_name, JSONObject.NULL);
    }
}
```

Now this might be a little different depending on which JSON library and version you are using.  Feel free to include those details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:

```
else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) {
   //Handle the column "Employee State of Residence" differently
   if(column_name.equals("Employee State of Residence")){
      String stateValue = rsNew.getString(column_name);
      obj.put(column_name, stateValue==null?"":stateValue );
    }else{
   //Else do it the regular way
     obj.put(column_name, rsNew.getString(column_name));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I might not want to hardcode the column name here because for different SQL queries, I may run into similar issue

Answer (score 0):

#### Using standard SQL/JSON

In a lot of SQL dialects, you'll find native SQL/JSON support, [so there's no need to write all of this SQL/JSON glue code in your Java client application](https://blog.jooq.org/stop-mapping-stuff-in-your-middleware-use-sqls-xml-or-json-operators-instead/). I'm assuming you're using Oracle, so you could use pretty much standard SQL/JSON like this:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(
  KEY 'Employee State of Residence' VALUE "Employee State of Residence",
  KEY 'Employee Count' VALUE "Employee Count"
  NULL ON NULL -- Use this instead of ABSENT ON NULL to retain null values
  RETURNING CLOB -- In case the data sizes are big
) RETURNING CLOB)
FROM t
```

Looks much better than your complex loop? If your resulting documents become big, just add `RETURNING CLOB` to your query, though that's optional.

If you're not using Oracle after all, other database products support SQL/JSON to some extent, or have their own non-standard syntax that can do the same thing.

#### Using third party libraries

If you're open to using a third party library for your SQL/JSON glue code, you could use [jOOQ, which has extensive support for these SQL/JSON features](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/). It can help with the tricky edge cases, e.g. when you need to embed `BOOLEAN` values, nested JSON data structures, or add vendor agnosticity to the query, etc.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)