# Json to object and back in python like java

Tags: python, jsonpickle

I am using jsonpickle which creates JSON with "py/object" with parameter `unpicklable=True`. If I need `unpicklable=False` type simple JSON, is there any library which does this like in Java?

It is very weird to put long "py/object" names in JSON.as these names are specific to application

Answer (score -1):

does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607444/how-to-serialize-object-to-json) solve the problem? 
if you are trying to serialize arbitrary classes and have java understand without prior class def you'll have to use some form of reflection, and worst case run time compilation.

personally i would look for a more structured way to achieve this like a command based system where the loaded classes can run lists of predefined commands giving better separation

Comment: are you referring to Gson library for java ?
my question is  is there something like this in python I found jsonpickle which requires "py/object"  in json structure

so i was trying to find something clean like Gson

Comment: if you just want a json seriliser in python then `import json`, load(open_file) loads(string_json)