Cannot print Java array (Essbase Java API)
I am trying to print an array without success.
I searched and tried several methods without success.
Here is the link to javadoc: listdbfiles. Should I use an enumerator or iterator?
Code:
EssDBFILEINFO[] PagSize = cube.listDbFiles(IEssCube.ESS_FILETYPE_DATA);

System.out.println(PagSize.length);
            
for (int i = 0; i < PagSize.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(PagSize[i]);
}
           
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(PagSize));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(PagSize));

Output:
7
com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@1324409e
com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@2c6a3f77
com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@246ae04d
com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@62043840
com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@5315b42e
com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@2ef9b8bc
com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@5d624da6
[com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@1324409e, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@2c6a3f77, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@246ae04d, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@62043840, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@5315b42e, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@2ef9b8bc, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@5d624da6]
[com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@1324409e, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@2c6a3f77, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@246ae04d, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@62043840, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@5315b42e, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@2ef9b8bc, com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@5d624da6]



Does your class EssDBFILEINFO actually @Override the toString() method?

You get output like com.essbase.api.datasource.EssDBFILEINFO@1324409e if the EssDBFILEINFO class doesn't override toString to print something more useful.

You should print the serialized-Version of your your Array(or the single EssDBFILEINFO-Object), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607444/how-to-serialize-object-to-json

In fact, you are correctly printing the contents of the array. That's not what your problem is. Your problem is that you're not printing the contents of the elements of the array. For that, you need to figure out which fields of the EssDBFILEINFO objects you want to print out, and print them.

OK I missed the following methods...
Thank you for the hints !
    for (int i = 0; i < PagSize.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(PagSize[i].getFileSize());
    }


